# NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getInsetsController()

Tags: android, android-studio

I upgrade my app to SDK 30. I saw that FLAG_FULLSCREEN deprecated. Then, i changed the code with this;

```
final WindowInsetsController insetsController = getWindow().getInsetsController();
if (insetsController != null) {
    insetsController.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
}
```

but I am getting this error when i try to run my app on API 26.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getInsetsController()Landroid/view/WindowInsetsController; in class Landroid/view/Window; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.view.Window' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
```

Answer (score 12):

Google is currently working on a Compat version of WindowInsetsContrloller.
This way, you won't need to branch if/else by android API level (as presented in @PerracoLabs's answer).
On Compat version of WindowInsetsContrloller we don't need to use getWindow().setFlags() because window.insetsController?.hide() will work on all android versions.

**Update:**

They already made it - class androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsControllerCompat.
You'll need to use androidx.core 1.5.0-alpha02 or greater.

My code example:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

    hideSystemBars()
}

private fun hideSystemBars() {
    val insetsControllerCompat = WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView)
    insetsControllerCompat.systemBarsBehavior = BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    insetsControllerCompat.hide(systemBars())
}

private fun showSystemBars() {
    val insetsControllerCompat = WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView)
    insetsControllerCompat.show(systemBars())
}
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me for android R

Answer (score 4):

When finding deprecation warnings you must perform API-level {if /else}  condition branching, to handle both scenarios, so, new code for newer API levels / old code for older API levels.

The deprecation warning will still appear if you target a high API level above the deprecation level, and is optional to suppress it, and also valid to leave the warning to easily spot it for future potential removal. In the next example it is suppressed.

**Note** that Google may offer you in some cases **Compat** libraries, which internally perform the necessary API branching, this is always the most desirable solution when a **Compat** library for a developer's specific issue is available.

For your specific case you can do as next:

**Java**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    final WindowInsetsController controller = getWindow().getInsetsController();
    
    if (controller != null)
        controller.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
} 
else {
    //noinspection deprecation
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
}
else {
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
```

Comment: When I use this, i am getting deprecated warning still. What then is the purpose of using a new one?

Comment: I have updated the answer to suppress the warning, although this is optional, as is also common not to suppress deprecation warnings to easily spot them for future removal. The purpose of branching, is that the new code is what must be used when API >= 30, and the FLAG_FULLSCREEN flag, which has become deprecated, is what still must be used when older API < 30. The deprecation warning is still expected to appear anyway. When something is deprecated you must always perform a branching "If / Else" condition to handle both scenarios (new code for newer API level / old code for older API level).

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

Latest version is (FYI):

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0-alpha05'